# Scripting a database copy from MS Sql 2005 to 2008 without detach/backup/RDP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, scripting

My goal is to move a single SQL 2005 database to a seperate 2008 server.  The issue is my level of access to both servers.  On each I can only access the database and nothing else.  I cant create a backup file or detach the database because I don't have access to the file system or to create a proxy.

I've tried using the generate script function of sql 2005 management studio express to restore the schema but receive command not supported errors when attempting to execute the sql on the new database.  Similarly I tried using EMS SQL Manager 2005 Lite to script a backup of the schema and data but ran into similar problems.

How do I go about acomplishing this?  I can't seem to find any solutions outside of using the detach and backup functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I seemed to have got it.  I used the data extract function of Sql 2008 Management studio express to extract the tables and data.  I then used DB Extract 2010 to pull out my stored procedures.  So far everything seems to be working.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Well james it looks like you didn't get the primary keys so you'll have to replace those.  But that's ok, you had some pretty sloppy relationships anyway and I'm not just talking about the tables!  Hey yooooo